# Log spring Bean instantiation

Tags: java, spring

How can we log each bean instantiation in Spring?

- I wish to log a message every time a bean is initialized.
- I have N number of bean and I don't want to put any logger on init method for each bean.
- I see this as a cross-cutting concern, but not sure how to achieve this.

Is there a way.?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a `BeanPostProcessor`

```
@Component
public class LogBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
        LOGGER.log(String.format("Bean instantiated with name %s and class %s", beanName, bean.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting logging level of `org.springframework.beans.factory` to `TRACE` or `DEBUG`.

I use log4j2 with xml configuration:

`<logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="trace"/>`

Comment: Note that this will log all beans instantiated by the container, including infrastructure beans.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Spring's event listener (explained [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)) to listen for event. I believe the event you need to listen to is `ContextRefreshedEvent`, e.g.:

```
@Component
public class MyListener 
        implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: From Spring doc:

> Event raised when an ApplicationContext gets initialized or refreshed

So, ```onApplicationEvent``` is called when your app is ready (it is deployed or redeployed etc). And at that moment, beans were ALREADY created.